OLS - Visual Interpretation of var(β^​0​)


Hi guys! Could someone please help me with the interpretation of x_i^2? the drawing below is what I saw on the lecture but I'm having some trouble understanding what it means and why the mean is 0 in both of the drawings

What is $\beta_0$ in your model? The intercept? If so, here's a similar question with answer.

@Durden yup, it's the intercept but I want to understand it visually

Visually how? It's unclear how your scatter plot relates to the formulas below. The equations in your drawing simply say $\sum x_i^2 = \sum (x_i - 0)^2$, which is trivially true.

The professor used the drawings to show how a small ∑x_i^2 (left) and a larger ∑x_i^2 (right) look like. But I'm having some trouble understanding the drawings, especially the one on the right, with the mean being 0.

If you're wondering what is $\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i^2$, or why the variance of $x$ is equal to the mean of the square of $x$ minus the square of the mean of $x$, have a look at the answer here.

The mean obviously is not zero at the right, because all the $x_i$ are positive.

@whuber I was thinking the same thing and that's why it seemed confusing but that is what the professor draw and why the formula on the highlighed part doesn't include the mean of x

The highlighted formula does include a term for the mean: that's one to interpret the drawing.  The point is that the sum of $x_i^2$ is the variance when the mean is assumed to be zero.
